# Using Left Join along with Where Condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as follows:

```
order_detail
Fields: order_id, name, total, quantity

order
Fields: id, order_date
```

For each record in order there are multiple records in order_detail.

I am looking at getting the following result.

Show sum (total) and sum(quantity) grouped by name where order_date is between 3/1/2015 and 2/29/2016. In this I want to see only top 10 items sorted by total. I wrote the following query, but I just keep getting syntax error:

```
select od.name, sum(od.total) AS revenue, sum(od.quantity) as quantity FROM order_detail od 
LEFT JOIN order o ON o.id=od.order_id
GROUP BY od.name ORDER BY revenue desc limit 10 
WHERE (o.completed_at)::text >= '3/1/2015' and (o.completed_at)::text <= '2/29/2016'
```

Can you please help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: Your `WHERE` needs to be before your `GROUP BY`

Comment: If you include checks on columns in a `JOIN`ed table then you effectively turn that `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, so you'd might as well just use the `INNER JOIN` and move those criteria into the `JOIN` clause. (with a few exceptions that typically involve checking for `NULL` values.

Comment: Moving WHERE before GROUP does resolve the error, but it results in an empty table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move those conditions into the `JOIN` condition. Putting them into the `where` condition effectively changes the outer join into an inner join

You should also not compare dates as strings, but as dates:

```
select od.name, 
       sum(od.total) AS revenue, 
       sum(od.quantity) as quantity 
FROM order_detail od 
   LEFT JOIN order o ON o.id=od.order_id
                    AND o.completed_at >= DATE '2015-03-01'
                    AND o.complated_dat <= DATE '2016-02-29'
GROUP BY od.name 
ORDER BY revenue desc limit 10
```